# videojs player returns wrong total duration from index.mpd file

Tags: html5-video, video.js

<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 [http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd%22) id="201" type="static" **mediaPresentationDuration="PT5742.720S"** minBufferTime="PT30S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011">
<Period start="PT0.000S" id="1" **duration="PT5580.720S"**>

As we have different mediaPresentationDuration and duration times in index.mpd file, and videojs player i am using picks duration instead of mediaPresentationDuration which produces wrong total time and thats why i am not getting onEnd event as well.
I am using videojs-contrib-eme to play dash content.
Please help me on why videojs not picking mediaPresentationDuration.

I am expecting videojs to pick mediaPresentationDuration instead of duration from index.mpd file